# О  ", если" и ", даже если"

Tags: семантика

Как пояснить мальчику смысловое отличие между предложениями "Q, если P." и "Q, даже если P."?

Примечание: P и Q - пропозициональные переменные.

Comment: имейте совесть! у мальчика каникулы!

Comment: Прочтено про "каникулы".

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения логики:

(1)Событие Q произойдет при условии события P.

(2)Событие Q произойдет обязательно, в том числе при  условии события P.

С точки зрения грамматики:

В первом случае мы имеем обусловленность двух высказываний, выраженных с помощью простого союза ЕСЛИ. Мы пойдем гулять, если будет хорошая погода.

Во втором случае  наличие частицы ДАЖЕ  меняет отношение двух высказываний: из условных они превращаются в условно-уступительные: Мы пойдём гулять (в любом случае), даже если будет дождь. (Сравнить: мы пошли гулять, хотя на улице шел дождь).

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.